# Contain Background Image to Avada Container

Tags: css, wordpress

I use avada for a clients site, and the design direction they have chosen requires an imaged background. When I place the image, and preview the site, the image is zoomed in to fit the space by default from Avada. It gives me the option in the container Background Options to change the "center center, center top, etc" but I want to have the image fit the container. Is there a way I can do this is additional CSS or inline?

Comment: did my answer make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `background-size` rule with `background-size: contain !important;`

To test this out, add a class name 'contain-img' (without a period) to the container, and add this rule to the page-level CSS (near the top):

```
.contain-img {
    background-size: contain !important;
}
```